# How to update partial of html using ES6 syntax with angular-webpack-seed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

this is not the angular I used to know, and I don't know where is a good example I can mimic, so I ask you for help.

[image]

I want to update the right part of this page without refresh the page using ES2015 + angularJS + Webpack framework.

I want to have different controllers, now the page has a controller as 'home'. **When the user click the left side, I want to update the right part of it, and use a separate controller for the right part.**

What I know is, I can just write `ng-controller = ...` But using the ES2015 and webpack, I start to confuse.

This is what I current have.

First, the index.html

```
<html ng-app="abc" ng-strict-di>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>{%= o.htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" ui-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then the router.js

```
import HomeController from './home';

export default function routes($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      template: require('./home.html'),
      controller: HomeController,
      controllerAs: 'home',
    })
    .state('android', {
      url: '/android',
      template: '<h2>This is Android</h2>',
      parent: 'home'
    });
}'
```

Question here, **this `'export default function routers($stateProvider) {}'` is not the way I know to write angular, can someone explain a little here?**

This is how I define my HomeController, **I want to follow the standard and create different controller for the right part of page**.

```
export default class HomeController {
constructor($http) {
    'ngInject';
    this.currentPlatform = '';
    this.platforms = [
      {
        displayName: "WEB PORTAL",
        value : "WEB PORTAL"
      },
      {
        displayName: "ROKU",
        value : "ROKU"
      },
      {
        displayName: "Android",
        value : "ANDROID"
      },
      {
        displayName: "iPhone",
        value : "iPhone"
      }
    ];
    this.$http = $http;
    this.projectName = "";
    this.appId = "";
    this.version = "";
    this.fieldData = "";

  }
}
```

Also I have to show you the home.html, so you can give me instructions based on that.

```
<div class="home">
  <div class="title">
    <h1 class="h3">Build/Configure Apps</h1>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="platform in home.platforms" ng-class="{active: home.isSelected(platform.value)}">
            <a ng-click="home.setPlatform(platform.value)">{{platform.displayName}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="form-inline form-group">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="appId" class="control-label">App Id:</label>
            <input type="text" name="appId" ng-model="home.appId" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary col-sm-8" ng-click="home.makeAjaxCall()">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h2>This right content should be updated when click on the left nav bar, but the left should not</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance！

Comment: The code sample here is using the `controllerAs:` syntax instead of using `$scope`.  There are quite a few articles around describing this, questions posted here regarding it, and it is recommended in John Papa's excellent [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controlleras-view-syntax).  The question isn't *really* about most of the things you mention;  Read up on the `controllerAs` concept and if you are still confused, refine the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is here is rather general, but since I know the background I can answer it in detail.

Your first question:

> export default function routers($stateProvider) {}

That's ES6 + angular-ui-router - you should define a state by using UI-Router specific routes.

In order to get your design implemented, you'd need to change `static/index.html`, to:

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
       <div ui-view="navbar">
       </div>
       <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and define a navbar view in the stateprovider, to point to navbar.html which will contain:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="platform in home.platforms" ng-class="{active: home.isSelected(platform.value)}">
    <a ng-click="home.setPlatform(platform.value)">{{platform.displayName}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('navbar', {
      template: require('./navbar.html'),
      controller: NavbarController,
      controllerAs: 'navbar',
    })
```

This should get you started.

Comment: [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view) should get you started with ui-router.